# Add Hubtile control to xaml programatically with device screen width Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, live-tile

I have started working With the Hubtile. I'm trying to add a hubtile to a list, with the Hubtile filling the device screen width. I am adding it to a ContentPanel, however i think this is wrong - i need to show the tiles as a list, inside the app with wide tile(max screen width) property, how can i achieve this? Have a look at my code so far:

```
            //Project 1
        HubTile project1 = new HubTile();
        project1.GroupTag = "projects";
        project1.Title = "RLE Kunnskap til andre prøve";
        project1.Message = "Kunnskap til den andre prøven i RLE";
        project1.Width = Convert.ToDouble(Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth.ToString());

        //Add to mainContentPanel for a sample view
        mainContentPanel.Children.Add(project1);
```

I managed to create the size rectangular using the Tilesize property, I was trying all the time figuring out how, but this answer saved me.

```
        //Tile 2
        TileSize tilesize = new TileSize();
        tilesize = TileSize.Large;
        HubTile Tile2= new HubTile();
        Tile2.Size = tilesize;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not that you are adding it to a content panel. If you want to use a list I think that a ListBox would be suited better. Also you can use a ListBox really easy for a MVVM design pattern. The main issue in your setting is, that the HubTile has four preset sizes. The sizes are compliant with the tiles on the start screen, ensuring a coherent experience throughout the system. If you still need a wider tile than `Size="Large"`,you need a custom template.

To do this, right click a HubTile in the designer view and select Template->Edit Template->Edit copy. Create a new style either on the page where you want to use the tile. You can then edit the newly created style and reset all the "width" properties to "auto". This way, the tile width can be easily adjusted. The finished style will then look something like this:

```
<Style x:Key="HubTileFullWidthStyle" TargetType="toolkit:HubTile">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="173"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:HubTile">
                <Border x:Name="Container">
                    <Border.Resources>
                        <CubicEase x:Key="HubTileEaseOut" EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                    </Border.Resources>
                    <Border.Height>
                        <Binding Converter="{StaticResource HeightConverter}" Path="Size" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                    </Border.Height>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ImageStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition x:Name="ExpandedToSemiexpanded" From="Expanded" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.85" To="Semiexpanded">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="TitlePanel">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource HubTileEaseOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="{Binding Size, ConverterParameter=-1, Converter={StaticResource HeightConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource HubTileEaseOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.85" Value="{Binding Size, ConverterParameter=-0.4566, Converter={StaticResource HeightConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="RotationX" Storyboard.TargetName="ViewportProjection">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource HubTileEaseOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="0.0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualTransition>
                                <VisualTransition x:Name="SemiexpandedToExpanded" From="Semiexpanded" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.85" To="Expanded">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="TitlePanel">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource HubTileEaseOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="{Binding Size, ConverterParameter=-0.4566, Converter={StaticResource HeightConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource HubTileEaseOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.85" Value="{Binding Size, ConverterParameter=-1, Converter={StaticResource HeightConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualTransition>
                                <VisualTransition x:Name="SemiexpandedToCollapsed" From="Semiexpanded" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.85" To="Collapsed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="TitlePanel">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource HubTileEaseOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="{Binding Size, ConverterParameter=-0.4566, Converter={StaticResource HeightConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource HubTileEaseOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.85" Value="0.0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualTransition>
                                <VisualTransition x:Name="CollapsedToExpanded" From="Collapsed" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.85" To="Expanded">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="TitlePanel">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource HubTileEaseOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="0.0"/>
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource HubTileEaseOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.85" Value="{Binding Size, ConverterParameter=-1, Converter={StaticResource HeightConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualTransition>
                                <VisualTransition x:Name="ExpandedToFlipped" From="Expanded" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.85" To="Flipped">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="TitlePanel">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource HubTileEaseOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="{Binding Size, ConverterParameter=-1, Converter={StaticResource HeightConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="Image">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.185" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackPanel">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.185" Value="Visible"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="RotationX" Storyboard.TargetName="ViewportProjection">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource HubTileEaseOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="0.0"/>
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource HubTileEaseOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.85" Value="180.0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualTransition>
                                <VisualTransition x:Name="FlippedToExpanded" From="Flipped" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.85" To="Expanded">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="TitlePanel">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource HubTileEaseOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="{Binding Size, ConverterParameter=-1, Converter={StaticResource HeightConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="Image">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.185" Value="Visible"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackPanel">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.185" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="RotationX" Storyboard.TargetName="ViewportProjection">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource HubTileEaseOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="180.0"/>
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource HubTileEaseOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.85" Value="360.0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualTransition>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="{Binding Size, ConverterParameter=-1, Converter={StaticResource HeightConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="TitlePanel"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RotationX" Storyboard.TargetName="ViewportProjection"/>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="Image">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="Visible"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Semiexpanded">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="{Binding Size, ConverterParameter=-0.4566, Converter={StaticResource HeightConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="TitlePanel"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Collapsed"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Flipped">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="{Binding Size, ConverterParameter=-1, Converter={StaticResource HeightConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="TitlePanel"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="180.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RotationX" Storyboard.TargetName="ViewportProjection"/>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="Image">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackPanel">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="Visible"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <StackPanel x:Name="Viewport" Height="{Binding Size, Converter={StaticResource HeightConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                        <StackPanel.Projection>
                            <PlaneProjection x:Name="ViewportProjection" CenterOfRotationY="0.25"/>
                        </StackPanel.Projection>
                        <Grid x:Name="TitlePanel" Height="{Binding Size, ConverterParameter=2, Converter={StaticResource HeightConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                <CompositeTransform/>
                            </Grid.RenderTransform>
                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.Row="0">
                                <TextBlock Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontSize="41" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" LineHeight="39" Margin="10,0,0,6" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="{TemplateBinding Title}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Grid x:Name="BackPanel" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="{Binding Size, Converter={StaticResource HeightConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                <Grid.Projection>
                                    <PlaneProjection CenterOfRotationY="0.5" RotationX="180"/>
                                </Grid.Projection>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="NotificationBlock" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" LineHeight="32" Margin="8,8,0,6" Grid.Row="0" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="{TemplateBinding Notification}"/>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="MessageBlock" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" LineHeight="23.333" Margin="10,10,10,6" Grid.Row="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{TemplateBinding Message}"/>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="BackTitleBlock" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}" Margin="10,0,0,6" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Border x:Name="Image" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.Row="1">
                                <Image Height="{Binding Size, Converter={StaticResource HeightConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Source="{TemplateBinding Source}" Stretch="UniformToFill" Width="{Binding Size, Converter={StaticResource WidthConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```