# How to change Tilesize of Hubtile dynamically?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want to change the Tilesize of hubtile dynamically.I want to display all size of hubtile in my home page i.e Small,Medium and Large.I know that we can do it with Hubtile control and I also have prepared a page with Medium Tilesize hub tile with 2 columns and rows based on number of tiles. Now can anyone suggest,how to use all sizes and also space or margin can be maintained.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to change the size of the `hubtile` by changing the height and the width of it as its already predefined. Have a look at this one for reference:

[Not able to create large size HubTile in WP8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21965020/)

Comment: Thanks @Kulasangar, you are right,but you might be knowing that there are 4 values for TileSize( i.e. Default,Small,Medium and Large).Now my issue is I want to use all this sizes and the output page should be properly organized.

Comment: You're sure that you used the `TileSize` property to assign the Tile size? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20152127/

Comment: Yes Kulasangar I will kept it TileSize.Medium and there are 2 columns so in one row,two tiles will be displayed,so now I am asking is it possible to use all sizes and they are displayed also properly.